# correlated subquery between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have two tables:

[image]

and I am trying to apply the same logic as: http://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery (last example)

and I came up with this:

```
SELECT id, project_name, 
    slug = (SELECT slug 
            FROM project_slugs ps 
            WHERE ps.project_id = p.id 
            ORDER BY created ASC 
            LIMIT 1) 
FROM projects p;
```

However I get the error "#1054 - Unknown column 'slug' in 'field list'". I realize the slug field doesn't exist in the `projects` table but neither does the `OrderCount` field in the example. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be

```
SELECT 
   id,
   project_name,
     (SELECT slug FROM 
       project_slugs ps 
       WHERE ps.project_id = p.id 
       ORDER BY created ASC LIMIT 1) as slug 
 FROM projects p;
```

where the subquery is known as slug which is an alias, this can be any name.

Comment: Out of curiosity, the last example in the link I showed didn't have an alias for the field (didn't exist in either table). How did that work?

Comment: to be honest i think this syntax (OP) will work to some database types but if you want to be consistent all the time just use the standard format

Comment: @Alex That website seems to be for SQL-Server, although I'm not sure that makes a difference there. I think the syntax of the last example is wrong. When you write `xxx = yyy` in the `SELECT` list, it's a comparison, not assigning a name to an expression.